# React web redirect file

Tags: javascript

is there a way to redirect pdf file? Let' say that I have two pdf files 'oldFile.pdf' and 'newFile.pdf'. There is a link to oldFile let's say www.myWeb.com/files/oldFile.pdf. I stopped using oldFile.pdf and I would like to replace it with newFile.pdf. Is there a way that the path above will open newFile.pdf instead of the old one? I heard that it is possible by proxy but I couldn't make it work with specific files but with folders.

Comment: Give us your code ( your attempt ) , we will give you an elegant solution. We cannot build an abstract answer.

Comment: Are you looking at a React solution ?? Why the title ?

Comment: The code is quite complex. I will think about how can I post some code.

Comment: Before posting any code, please read [mcve].

Comment: @klugjo I working with the react and I couldn't think of a better title, I am sorry if it's not correct. Can you suggest a better title?

Comment: Using client-side JavaScript, you could at most manipulate the href attribute of existing link elements inside your page/app. But if you want users that reach this URL in other ways (search engine result, social share, bookmark, ...) to get the new document as well, then you have to do this on the server.

Comment: Redirects are something that should be handled by the HTTP server.